# C++ Getting memory addresses of objects instead of the values the object has

Tags: c++

Having a little trouble. So I'm working on this to simulate traffic at an intersection. So far I have a class of the vehicle, the class where I do the processing, and the driver along with the two enum classes (street and direction) of the vehicle.

From v.toString() in Processor after switch statement:

A sample output: http://gyazo.com/49bb512fc063493e1083d5d4d57ab0d9 [Screenshot.]

EDIT 1: When having spaces something like this looks like the enums are okay.

http://gyazo.com/f96d7bb42cab5f3231d5a32d16b9ca82 [Screenshot.]

Here is what I have so far:

```
//Direction.h

#ifndef DIRECTION_H
#define DIRECTION_H


enum direction
{
    E = 0,
    W,
    N,

};

#endif

//Street.h

#ifndef STREET_H
#define STREET_H


enum street
{
    Main = 0,
    Church,
};

#endif

//Processor.h

#ifndef PROCESSOR_H
#define PROCESSOR_H
#include "Vehicle.h"
#include "Street.h"
#include "Direction.h"



class Processor
{
    private:
    int vCount; //number of cars created
    int carTime;
    direction tempDirect;
    street tempRoad;
    int lanes; //What queue its going in
    int vNum; // number of vehicle

    public:
    void createVehicles(int, int);
    void Traffic();


};

#endif

//Vehicle.h

#ifndef VEHICLE_H  
#define VEHICLE_H



#include "Street.h"
#include "Direction.h"


class Vehicle
{
   private:
    int vehicleNumber;
    int arrivalTime;
    int departureTime;
    street road;
    direction direct; 

   public:
    Vehicle(int, street, direction, int);
    Vehicle();
    void setVehicleNumber(int);
    int getVehicleNumber();
    void setArrivalTime(int);
    int getArrivalTime();
    void setDirection(direction);
    direction getDirection();
    void setStreet(street);
    street getStreet();
    void toString();


};

#endif


#include "Vehicle.h"
#include "Street.h"
#include "Direction.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


    Vehicle::Vehicle()
    {

    }


    Vehicle::Vehicle(int vNum, street b , direction a, int aTime)
    {
        vehicleNumber = vNum;
        arrivalTime = aTime;
        road = b;
        direct = a;

    }

    void Vehicle::toString()
    {
        cout<< vehicleNumber <<  road << direct << arrivalTime << endl;
    }




//Processor.cpp

#include "Vehicle.h"
#include "Processor.h"
#include "Street.h"
#include "Direction.h"
#include <stdlib.h> //random
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime> //to reset random seed so not the same number is generated every time
using namespace std;


void Processor::createVehicles(int min, int max)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int count = rand()%(max-min)+min; //how many vehicles will be created

    for(int i = 0 ; i < count; i++)
    {
        lanes = rand() % 6;
        switch(lanes)
        {
            case 0 : tempRoad = Church;
                tempDirect = W;
                break;
            case 1 : tempRoad = Church;
                tempDirect = E;
                break;
            case 2 : tempRoad = Main;
                tempDirect = N;
                break;
            case 3 : tempRoad = Main;
                tempDirect = W;
                break;
            case 4 : tempRoad = Main;
                tempDirect = N;
                break;
            case 5 : tempRoad = Main;
                tempDirect = E;
                break;


        }

        Vehicle v((vNum + 1), tempRoad, tempDirect, carTime);

        vNum++;
        vCount++;
        v.toString();

    }





}

//Driver.cpp

using namespace std;
#include "Processor.h"
#include <iostream>



int main()
{
    Processor process;

    process.createVehicles(8, 12);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: what happens if you add some spaces in the output?  Change`cout<< vehicleNumber <<  road << direct << arrivalTime << endl;` to `cout<< vehicleNumber << " " <<  road << " " << direct << " " << arrivalTime << endl;`

Comment: @NathanOliver Check the edit I just posted! So it looks like the enums give their integers which is okay I guess, but the addresses of the vehicle Number and arrivalTime show up.

Comment: Do you initialize `vNum` and `carTime`?

Comment: Please strip your code down to a MVCE.

Comment: @aschepler Ah, that's probably it. Wow, can't believe I made that mistake. Where can I initialize it? I know in Java you can do it at the class level but I'm not 100% sure how to do that in c++.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier I trimmed it down, is that good?

Comment: By the way, prefer not to use single letter identifiers as identifier names.  For example `N` can represent many words, while `NORTH` is less ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you are using pointers or taking the addresses of variables.  Printing the address of a variable is usually like this:

```
  Direction d;
  d = S;
  cout << (void *)(&d) << endl;
```

I noticed you are printing the `enum` variable.  When you print an `enum` variable, the compiler will print out the *ordinal* or assigned value of the enumeration identifier; not the name or text for the identifier.

### Printing `enum` identifier names

Printing out the `enum` identifier names involves *associating* the `enum` value with text.  Two popular methods are using `std::map` and a lookup table.

### The Lookup Table

Create an array of structures and search the structures:

```
enum Direction { NORTH, WEST, SOUTH, EAST};
struct Direction_Entry
{
  Direction d;
  char const * text;
};

char const * Direction_To_String(enum Direction d)
{
  static const Direction_Entry dir_table[] =
  {
    {NORTH, "North"}, {WEST, "West"},
    {SOUTH, "South"}, {EAST, "East"},
  };
  static const unsigned int dir_entries =
    sizeof(dir_table) / sizeof(dir_table[0]);
  static char const text_unknown_dir[] = "Unknown direction";
  unsigned int i = 0U;
  char const * name = 0;
  for (i = 0U; i < dir_entries; ++dir)
  {
    if (dir_table[i].d == d)
    {
      name = dir_table[i].text;
    }
  }
  return name;
}
```

A similar function can be used for converting from text to `enum`.

### Using a `std::map`

The `std::map` can also be used:

```
const std::string& Direction_To_String(Direction d)
{
  static const std::string unknown_dir = "Unknown Direction";
  static std::map<Direction, d> dir_map;
  if (dir_map.empty())
  {
    dir_map[NORTH] = "North"; dir_map[WEST] = "West";
    dir_map[SOUTH] = "South"; dir_map[EAST] = "East";
  }
  const std::map<Direction, d>::const_iterator iter = dir_map.find(d);
  if (iter != dir_map.end())
  {
    return iter->second;
  }
  return Unknown_Direction;
}
```

Comment: My bad. I thought the weird number was an address. You can see I'm pretty new to C++.

Comment: Thanks for the function. I'll look into the map thing, how could I initialize the values of vehicleNumber and time outside createVehicles? I plan to call it multiple times to make more cars and don't want the time and number to keep getting reset to 1 and 0 respectively.

Comment: You will need a `static` variable, initialize it in the declaration.  Increment it in the function.  This would be another question because examples don't visualize well in comment sections.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for your help! Just need to figure out the enum thing. I made them static in the .h file and initialized up top in the processor.cpp.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting memory address but you are getting uninitialized data.  Spliting up the output in you `toString()` as

```
cout<< vehicleNumber << " " << road << " " << direct << " " << arrivalTime << endl
```

You can see that `vehicleNumber` is being incremented by one for each vehicle.  If it was a memeory address the value would more than likely be changing by 4 each time.  The reason that it is some weird number is you never give it a value so it becomes whatever is in that memory location the variable happens to reside.  `arrivalTime` never changes because there is nowhere in your code where you change it and it also gets a garbage value for the same reason `vehicleNumber` does.

Comment: Ah. You can see I'm pretty new to C++. For some reason I thought the weird number was a memory address, not because i never initialized it.

Thanks for your help.